# How to use Binding in trigger, to change another control in WPF?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, triggers

I have this DataTemplate in style. I have two properties for Image's Source (Image and ImageHover). Now its Image. So I want to change it to ImageHover when the List item from the List Box is hovered by the mouse. How can I make this kind of Binding - Binding in trigger, to change another control's property ?

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MetroListBoxItemTemplate">
        <Grid Name="grid_menu">

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="110"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Name="menu_image" Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="Uniform" Width="40" Height="40" >

            </Image>

            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="5">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title, FallbackValue=Title}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="20"
                        Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem, Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=Foreground}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

I use the template here

```
 <ListBox 
            x:Name="main_menu" HorizontalAlignment="Left"   Margin="8,8,0,8" Width="160"
                 ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource MetroListBoxItemTemplate}" 
     ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource MetroListBoxItemStyle}"
     ItemsSource="{Binding Menu}">

</ListBox>
```

Comment: ItemContainerStyle should reference to Style, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, MetroListBoxItemStyle is a style. But is it relevant to the problem ?

Comment: It is since in style you can determine if mouse is over, in DataTemplate you cannot.